# Setting Bool attribute of an NSManagedObject throws "Uncaught exception in iOS 10"

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I am upgrading my app to iOS 10 / swift 3

So constructing an `NSManagedObject` with a dictionary (values received from remote db) this way...

```
    let writerDictionary = [
        ...: writer.id,
        ...: writer.name,
        ...: writer.picture,
        ...: writer.publicationID,
        ...: writer.language,
        ...: writer.country
    ]

    let newWriter = Writer(dictionary: writerDictionary, context: SHARED_CONTEXT)
```

`isFavorite` is an `NSManaged` property that I set manually to `true` with `newWriter.isFavorite = true` right after constructing the `newWriter` object before saving the context -

This line crashes with Uncaught Exception in iOS 10 - Previously there was no problem whatsoever with iOS 9

I have also tried `newWriter.setValue(true, forKey: "isFavorite")` - While it does not crash the app, the bool value `isFavorite` remains `false` unchanged.

Any ideas? This is my Writer subclass of NSManagedObject

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Writer)

class Writer: NSManagedObject {

    // Attributes also in the database
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var picture: String?
    @NSManaged var publicationID: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var language: String
    @NSManaged var country: String
    @NSManaged var lastArticle: Date

    // Attributes only in the iOS app
    @NSManaged var isFavorite: Bool           // Initial value is false
    @NSManaged var hasNewArticles: Bool

    // Relationship objects
    @NSManaged var publication: Publication
    @NSManaged var articles: [Article]

    var writerImage: UIImage? {
        get {
            return ImageCache.sharedCache.imageWithIdentifier("writers-" + String(id))
        }
        set {
            ImageCache.sharedCache.storeImage(newValue, withIdentifier: "writers-" + String(id))
        }
    }

    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }

    init(dictionary: [String : AnyObject], context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Writer", in: context)!
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

        id = ...  
        name = ...  
        picture = ...  
        publicationID = ...  
        language = ...  
        country = ...  
        lastArticle = ...  
    }

    override func prepareForDeletion() {
        if let _ = writerImage {
            writerImage = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Uncaught exception" is not a crash reason. What are the exception details?

Comment: Nothing! This is all what I get in the console. "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: Put a breakpoint on exceptions and see where it crashes.

Comment: It crashes when I try set the `isFavorite` property to `true` in `newWriter.isFavorite = true` and the console doesn't give anything except the line between double quotes above.

Comment: Go to the latest line in the stack trace (on the left), and in the debugger type "po $arg1"

Comment: error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier '$arg1'
$arg1

Comment: You didn't execute the command on the correct stack frame.

Comment: @LeoNatan I have tried all of them now :D - same

Comment: Make sure you disable the Xcode filter of only user code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116398/discussion-between-ahmed-abdel-hady-khedr-and-leo-natan).

Comment: @LeoNatan - I just posted the solution. Your suggestion of breakpoint on exception with $arg1 kinda paved the way as well as a reply on Apple forums. Thanks...

Comment: Xcode 8 beta 2 as well as iOS 10 beta is out. See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

The current version of Swift 3 beta seems to have some flaw about treating properties prefixed with "is".

Adjusting the name of the property like this, solved it...

```
 @NSManaged @objc(isFavorite) var isFavorite: Bool
```

Comment: Damn, this was an issue with my var, which was data...

original
    `@NSManaged  var jsonData: NSData`

working
    `@NSManaged @objc(jsonData) var jsonData: NSData`

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in Xcode 8 beta 3 compiler.

From the release notes:

> Earlier Swift 3 betas implicitly renamed the property, getter, and
>   setter for @objc properties of type Bool whose names started with
>   “is”, to match the Objective-C naming conventions. (For example, a
>   Swift boolean property named isMagical generated an Objective-C
>   declaration of the form @property (nonatomic, getter=isMagical) BOOL
>   magical.) This turned out to cause more trouble than it was worth and
>   has been removed. (26847223)